# How to move an element in a sorted list and keep the CouchDb write "atomic"

Tags: database-design, data-structures, transactions, couchdb, atomic

I have elements of a list in couchdb documents. Let's say these are 3 elements in 3 documents:

```
{ "id" : "783587346", "type" : "aList", "content" : "joey", "sort" : 100.0 }
{ "id" : "358734ff6", "type" : "aList", "content" : "jill", "sort" : 110.0 }
{ "id" : "abf587346", "type" : "aList", "content" : "jack", "sort" : 120.0 }
```

A view retrieves all "aList" documents and displays them sorted by "sort".

Now I want to move the elements, when I want to move "jack" to the middle, I could do this atomic in one write and change it's sort key to 105.0. The view now returns the documents in the new sort order.

After a lot of sorting I could end up with sort keys like 50.99999 and 50.99998 after some years and in extreme situations run out of digits?

What can you recommend, is there a better way to do this? I'd rather keep the elements in seperate documents. Different users might edit different list elements in parallel.

And users might also change the document order at the same time (which also can get tricky when 2 users want to move two different documents (like joey and jill) to the end with let's say "sort" = 130.0 at the same time).

Maybe there is a much better way?

Did I miss something on CouchDb transactions?

Comment: I found out bulk updates cannot do transactions anymore in newer versions of couchdb http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API - kalrthorwald - aka

Comment: Yes, there was a very long mailing list discussion about that a while back. The short version is, CouchDB feels the same whether it is one node or a huge distributed cluster. A transactional bulk API cannot be supported in distributed operation. That is why atomicity is not guaranteed.

Comment: I have been thinking about this for a couple of days, not to mention speaking with some CouchDB developers. I will post the top two options ASAP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using the common pattern of a real number for user control of sorting.
That is a fine technique, recommended by Damien Katz. To move between adjacent documents `A` and `B`, then you set your `sort` field to the average of `A.sort` and `B.sort`.

This question has several parts.

### What about floating point precision?

Javascript `Number`s are double-precision IEEE-754 floating point numbers. They
have limited precision.

Doubles have a lot of precision. If this is human-initiated activity then it
will be a very long time before dragging and dropping hits the limit.
But you have two choices:

#### 1. Re-normalize the sort values in the background

Remember rewriting your line numbers in BASIC? Same thing.

Have a cron job or some other task ([NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) is getting popular)
to check for unacceptably close sort values and space them out. This 
could use sophisticated heuristics such as:

- Wait until the site is under low activity to fix the `sort`s
- Wait until a specific user to be inactive for X time before fixing his `sort`s
- Only make modifications which space out `sort` values but which never change
  the view result. In other words, if you have `0.001`, `0.002`, and `0.003`,
  move the `0.003` first to e.g. `0.100`, then change `0.002` to `0.005`. That
  may have a slight helpful effect in the UI but remember, replication may not
  copy these in the same order so the benefit is marginal, perhaps not worth
  the complexity.

#### 2. Use a decimal data type with unlimited precision

Instead of `sort` storing a Javascript `Number`, it could store a string from
*but not including* `"0.0"` through `"1.0"` (say, to 100 digits). Then a string sort is
also a numeric sort. (You have "anchors" at 0.0 and 1.0 which are invalid for documents. To insert a document in the first position, set `sort` to the average of 0.0 and the current first document. For the last position, `sort` is the average of the last document and 1.0.)

Next, your client (whoever calculates the `sort` value) needs
arbitrary-precision real number types. Java, Ruby, Python, pretty much all the
languages have them.  This post even inspired me to make a quick project,
[BigDecimal for Javascript](http://github.com/jhs/bigdecimal.js) which is the `BigDecimal`
code from Google Web Toolkit (which itself came from Apache Harmony). But there
are other implementations too.

I personally like `BigDecimal`. In your case however you would have to change your
code to use a string for `sort`. However the benefit is, you never have to re-normalize
the `sort`s to work around the precision.

### What about collisions from concurrent activity?

CouchDB is Relaxed. What will happen is what users expect. CouchDB
documents mimic the real world. As Chris Anderson says, "there are no
transactions in real life."

For three elements in a UI:

- ItemA
- ItemB
- ItemC

What if I move `A` after `C` and you move `B` after C? Clearly, the list will either be
`C B A` or `C A B`. Which should it be? That depends on your application?

Either, **it doesn't matter**: Great! CouchDB will order `A` and `B` arbitrarily and you 
will be fine. Users will infer (or see if your UI is good) that somebody else moved
the other item.

Or,**B must come before A because [some reason]**: Well then, your `sort` value is wrong.
It should include all relevant data to decide sub-sorts. For example, you can
`emit([120.000, doc.userLastName], doc)`. When users move docs to the same place, the
sort becomes alphabetical.

If you say, **A cannot be moved so soon after B moved** then that is also application
code that must be implemented regardless of the data store. In other words, it's not
a transactional thing, it is software logic. For dragging and dropping UI elements,
my feeling is, it's not worth it and the "it doesn't matter" solution is best.

Comment: In the case of unlimited precision, after I inserted N records into the database, wouldn't the sort value became N digits long? The 1st is 0.5, 2nd is 0.25, 3rd is 0.125, and so on. What if I have thousands of records?

Comment: The sort value would be log_10(N) digits long.

Answer (score 1):

Is the current system really atomic?  After all, to move jack between joey and jill, we need to know the values of joey and jill which requires that they were queried first.  It's perfectly feasible that in between the time 105.0 is calculated, the vales of joey and jill have also changed.  In fact, I believe the only way this could work in SQL land would be to lock the relevant rows while reordering took place, resulting in a serializing of re-order requests.

Perhaps more details concerning the problem would be more useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I get the values from a view, which includs the _rev field, I believe them to show me the state of the database at a given time. karlthorwald - aka

Answer (score 1):

What about adding 10 to anything >= 110, then updating the record 130 to 110 ?
That allows you to keep clean intervals. Not ideal for records that are frequently updated by multiple users, nor for huge tables, but I am using that technique successfully on a small and rather static table.